# Azkaban - HIve Job Failed

Tags: hadoop, hive, azkaban

I am trying to run hive job in azkaban

I was able to upload the hive job but the hive job is not getting executed properly.

```
ERROR [hive-demo] [Azkaban] Failed to build job executor for job hive-demoJob type     'hive' is unrecognized. Could not construct job[{hive.query.01: drop table words;, hive.query.03: describe words;, hive.query.02: create table words (freq int, word string) row format delimited fields terminated by ' ' stored as textfile;, working.dir: /home/hduser/Technology/azkaban/azkaban-executor/executions/44, azk.hive.action: execute.query, azkaban.job.attempt: 0, type: hive, hive.query.05: select * from words limit   10;, hive.query.04: load data local inpath "res/input" into table words;, user.to.proxy:   azkaban, hive.query.06: select freq, count(1) as f2 from words group by freq sort by f2 desc  limit 10;, parent = {azkaban.flow.flowid: hive-demo, azkaban.flow.execid: 44,  azkaban.flow.start.timezone: America/Los_Angeles, azkaban.flow.start.hour: 22,  azkaban.flow.start.second: 17, azkaban.flow.start.year: 2014,  azkaban.flow.start.milliseconds: 111, azkaban.flow.start.minute: 54,  azkaban.flow.start.timestamp: 2014-01-31T22:54:17.111-08:00, azkaban.flow.start.month: 01,  azkaban.flow.projectversion: 2, azkaban.flow.projectid: 4, azkaban.flow.uuid: 29a46293-cc95- 4c66-b2b1-51014205ce3b, azkaban.flow.start.day: 31, parent = {}}}] of type[hive]. 2014/02/01  12:24:17.295 +0530 ERROR [hive-demo] [Azkaban] Failed to build job type, skipping this job    2014/02/01 12:24:17.295 +0530 ERROR [hive-demo] [Azkaban] Job run failed! 2014/02/01 12:24:17.295 +0530 INFO [hive-demo] [Azkaban] Finishing job hive-demo at 1391237657295  2014/02/01 12:24:17.382 +0530 INFO [FlowRunnerManager] [Azkaban] Cleaning recently finished  2014/02/01 12:24:17.383 +0530 INFO [FlowRunnerManager] [Azkaban] Cleaning execution 43 from  recently finished flows list. 2014/02/01 12:24:17.408 +0530 INFO [hive-demo] [Azkaban] Job  Finished hive-demo with status FAILED 2014/02/01 12:24:17.463 +0530 INFO [hive-demo]  [Azkaban] Finishing up flow. Awaiting Termination 2014/02/01 12:24:17.463 +0530 INFO [hive- demo] [Azkaban] Setting flow status to Failed. 2014/02/01 12:24:17.464 +0530 INFO [hive- demo] [Azkaban] Flow is set to FAILED 2014/02/01 12:24:17.464 +0530 INFO [hive-demo]  [Azkaban] Setting end time for flow 44 to 1391237657464 2014/02/01 12:24:17.552 +0530 INFO  [FlowRunnerManager] [Azkaban] Flow 44 is finished. Adding it to recently finished flows  list. 2014/02/01 12:26:17.383 +0530 INFO [FlowRunnerManager] [Azkaban] Cleaning recently  finished 2014/02/01 12:26:17.384 +0530 INFO [FlowRunnerManager] [Azkaban] Cleaning execution  44 from recently finished flows list.
 ========================================================================
```

Here is the content in my plugin.properties

```
job.class=azkaban.jobtype.hiveutils.azkaban.HiveViaAzkaban

hive.home=HIVE_HOME

hive.aux.jars.path=/usr/lib/hive/lib
env.HIVE_HOME=$HIVE_HOME
env.HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=/usr/lib/hive/lib

#hive.jvm.args=-Dhive.querylog.location=. -Dhive.exec.scratchdir=/tmp/hive-    ${user.to.proxy} -Dhive.aux.jars.path=${hive.aux.jars.path}
jobtype.global.jvm.args=${hive.jvm.args}
```

this is my private.properties
              jobtype.classpath=$HADOOP_HOME/conf,$HADOOP_HOME/lib/*,$HIVE_HOME/lib/*,$HIVE_HOME/conf,/usr    /lib/hive/lib
    jobtype.class=azkaban.jobtype.HadoopJavaJob

```
hive.aux.jars.path=/usr/lib/hive/lib
env.HADOOP_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
env.HIVE_HOME=$HIVE_HOME
env.HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=/usr/lib/hive/lib

hive.home=$HIVE_HOME

jobtype.global.classpath=${hive.classpath.items}
  hive.classpath.items=./*,${hive.home}/lib/*,${hive.home}/conf/,${hive.aux.jars.path}/*,${had    oop.home}/*,${hadoop.home}/lib/*,${hadoop.home}/conf/
```

I have added the plugin folder in executor folder only.

Why is not detecting the job type. please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what is going on since you neither share the job itself nor logs, but try the following and let us know if this works. Create a file `test.job` with the following content:

```
type=hive
azk.hive.action=execute.query
hive.query=CREATE TABLE test(id INT, name STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
user.to.proxy=hadoop
```

and submit it as described in the '[creating flow](http://azkaban.github.io/azkaban2/documents/2.1/creatingflows.html)' section. For further details on the different types of jobs Azkaban (2.1) supports out of the box see the [job types/plugin documentation](http://azkaban.github.io/azkaban2/documents/2.1/jobtypes.html).

Comment: i am using hadoop cdh4 and hive 0.10 .. is it a version problem?

Comment: ERROR [hive-demo] [Azkaban] Failed to build job executor for job hive-demoJob type 'hive' is unrecognized.